# Use squelize find in jade

Tags: node.js, pug, sequelize.js

I am new to node.js / jade sequelize, the secnario i want to get to is, inside a jade file, can i do something like:

-Item.find( id ).on('success'), function(return) {
p return.name
p return.value
})

Tried this a couple of times but couldn't get it working.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

**No.**

That's not how views and templates work. We *do not* talk to the database in the view.

Before you render the view talk to the database.

Psuedo code:

```
Item.find(id).on("success", function(item) {
  res.render(view, {
    name: item.name,
    value: item.value
  });
});
```

Comment: But there is no reason to do this. Sequelize may as well be viewed as the "model" that talks to the database. And, in a lot of applications the fat-model approach works better.

Answer (score 2):

this is not a sequelize-specific problem, but a jade/mvc one. First, following the mvc pattern, you should load all needed data in the controller and pass it afterwards to the view. Furthermore the problem you are experiencing exists due to Jade's incompatibility with asynchronous function calls. Because sequelize is working asynchronously, you won't be able to get your data in the view.